# Pandas filling nulls with grouby value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill null values for all the numeric type columns in a dataframe.

The code below goes through each numeric column and groups by a categorical feature and calculates the median of the target column.

We then create a new column that copies over the values if it is present, but if it null, then it should copy over the value from the groupby based on the categorical value in the row where the n/a is present.

```
# fill in numeric nulls with median based on job
for i in dfint:
    print(i)

for i in dfint:
    if i in ["TARGET_BAD_FLAG", "TARGET_LOSS_AMT"]: continue
    print(i)
    group=df.groupby("JOB")[i].median()
    print(group)
    df["IMP_"+i]=df[i].fillna(group[group.index.get_loc(df.loc[df[i].isna(),"JOB"])])
    #the line below works but fills in all nulls with the median for the "Mgr" job category, the code above should find the job category for the null record and pull the groupby value 
    #df["IMP_"+i]=df[i].fillna(group[group.index.get_loc("Mgr")])
```

I seem to be having an issue with the function between the .get_loc, here is the output

```
TARGET_BAD_FLAG
TARGET_LOSS_AMT
LOAN
MORTDUE
VALUE
YOJ
DEROG
DELINQ
CLAGE
NINQ
CLNO
DEBTINC
LOAN
JOB
Mgr        18100
Office     16200
Other      15200
ProfExe    17300
Sales      14300
Self       24000
Name: LOAN, dtype: int64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-f8a76179c818> in <module>
      8     group=df.groupby("JOB")[i].median()
      9     print(group)
---> 10     df["IMP_"+i]=df[i].fillna(group[group.index.get_loc(df.loc[df[i].isna(),"JOB"])])
     11     #the line below works but fills in all nulls with the median for the "Mgr" job category, the code above should find the job category for the null record and pull the groupby value
     12     #df["IMP_"+i]=df[i].fillna(group[group.index.get_loc("Mgr")])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 )
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
   2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: 'Series([], Name: JOB, dtype: object)' is an invalid key
```

Is there a way to modify that line to do as intended

Comment: Please give original data and the  desired results. There maybe many ways to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
for i in dfint:
    if i in ["TARGET_BAD_FLAG", "TARGET_LOSS_AMT"]: continue
    print(i)
    df[f'IMP_{i}'] = df.groupby('JOB')[i].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this : `df.loc[df[i].isna(),"JOB"]` which will return you a pandas Series, not a key as requested by [pandas.Index.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)